# Overloaded Constructor in Abstract Class in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I have an abstract class in vb.net with two subclasses.  In the abstract class I have a constuctor that looks like this:

```
Public Sub New(arg1 as String, arg2 as String)
    Me.arg1 = arg1
    Me.arg2 = arg2
End Sub
```

I would like to create a second constructor that doesn't take any arguments and just initializes the args to default values.   It would look like this:

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.arg1 = "123"
    Me.arg2 = "456"
End Sub
```

When I attempt to create a new subclass using the second constructor the compiler complains that I'm missing two args to the constructor....  Is there a reason I can't overload the constructor in the abstract class?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post all of your class code? Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "abstract" in VB.  If you mean abstract in the c# sense (MustInherit in VB parlance), then you need to define both constructors in your subclasses, as constructors are not inherited.

Example:

```
Public MustInherit Class SuperClass
    Public Property ValueOne As String = String.Empty

    Public Property ValueTwo As String = String.Empty


    Public Sub New()

        Me.New("123", "456")

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal tValueOne As String, ByVal tValueTwo As String)

        Me.ValueOne = tValueOne
        Me.ValueTwo = tValueTwo

    End Sub    
End Class



Public Class SubClass
    Inherits SuperClass


    Public Sub New()

        MyBase.New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal tValueOne As String, ByVal tValueTwo As String)

        MyBase.New(tValueOne, tValueTwo)

    End Sub  

End Class
```

Comment: Abstract is a Computer Science term.

Comment: SubClass doesn't need to have both constructors just because its base class has both. The only rule is that it calls a constructor on the base class.

Comment: It's just semantics. I work between C# and VB.Net and I refer to everything based on C# terminology.

Answer (score 0):

If your second constructor is in the sub class, it must call the constructor in the base class.

```
Public Sub New() 
    MyBase.New("123", "456") 
End Sub
```